# Paraview create points array and set it as source array

Tags: paraview

Creating an array with `p_points = vtk.vtkPoints`

And then add data to it `p_points.InsertNextPoint(value).`

There is like 50000 points.

I want to put that point array in a source.

I tried with a programmable one with :

- servermanager fetch getPoints that give me the Point Array in it (p_array)
- Then with a loop `p_array.InsertNextPoint(p_points.GetPoint(index_point))`

But with no luck. The points array in the source  remain empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's working fine but it's quite slow when you have 50000 points (something like 400-500 seconds)

When I am using `servermanager.Fetch(ProgrammableSource).GetPoints().InsertNextPoints(x,y,z)`,
it's updating the array.

I can see it doing a Render(). And a time.sleep().

But at the end of the paraview script execution, the content seems to be blanked.

Am I accessing a temporary set pointer and then it's unset ?

Resolved :
I found a way using a *PolylineSource* instead of *ProgrammableSource*.

Thanks for your help Cory

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Programmable Source** with a script like:

```
import vtk

pts = vtk.vtkPoints()
for i in xrange(10):
  pts.InsertNextPoint(i, i, i)

output.SetPoints(pts)
```

The `output` object is pre-defined in the Python environment executed by the **Programmable Source** and is the output object of the source.